# Why decreases the pressure inside hollow organ, as volume is removed?

Tags: pressure, volume, medical-physics

I would like to explain in physical terms, why the pressure in the uterus falls, if volume (amniotic fluid) is removed.

So far as I understand, p in spheres is inversely proportional to the radius, according to the Law of Laplace P = 2T/R.
However, this is obviously not the correct explanation, since the pressure falls, as the radius decreases simultaneously.

Is there an alternative law, which explains this observation?

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure is linear with the density of the fuild. So I suppose the density of amniotic liquid is higher than that of air?

Comment: Yes, amniotic fluid is denser than air, however, there is no air in play within, or outside of the uterus. Outside of the uterus is the abdominal cavity, which is also "almost" purely liquid (usually asumed to be fully liquid).